# Can Microsoft Search Server index a Subversion repository

Tags: svn, search, search-server, microsoft-search-server

Our development team is moving to subverison and we would like to index the content on it.

Currently we use Visual Source Safe and keep the latest source on a shared drive for indexing.

We are also just starting to use Microsoft Search Server 2008 and as Subverison exposes a web interface we wanted to try and index it using the Search server. However the only piece of content that does get indexed is the root page. I suspect this is because it is an XML document that gets served up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbi,

Another way to do it would be to use a batch to run the `svn export` command and have the search server come back and index the file system a while later. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SVN's web interface, but you could install a [post-commit hook on the subversion server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) that updates a working copy on a shared drive and keep doing what you did with VSS.